# Random variable $X$ with values depending on the coin flipping

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

Let $X$ be random variable. Flip a coin, if the coin comes up head then $X=0$, if the the coin comes up tail then uniformly choose number in the interval $\left(0,1\right)$, let denote it $a$ and $X=a$. The task is to find distribution function $F(x)$ and how the density function $f(x)$ could look if we allow "infinite values". Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: What are your thoughts? Do you know the definition of the distribution function and have you tried to compute some values of it? Please improve your question by showing you made any attempts at the problem.

Comment: Yes of course I know definition of the distribution function, $F(x)=P(X<x)$. I think that $P(X=0)=\frac{1}{2}$ and $P(X \in (a,b))=\frac{1}{2}\cdot(b-a)$, for interval $(a,b) \subseteq (0,1)$. But I am not sure. Thanks

Comment: It should be $F(x) = P(X\le x)$, the rest looks ok. Clarify in your question what you already got and what specifically you are having trouble with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $x < 0$ you have $P(X\le x)=0$ since $X$ does not take negative values. For $0\le x\le 1$ note that
$$
P(X\le x) = P(\text{$X=0$ or $0<X\le x$}) = P(X=0) + P(X\in(0,x]).
$$
Can you take it from there?

Comment: Thank you, now I understand. But I stil not understand what it is mean how the density function $f(x)$ could look if we allow "infinite values". Thank you very much for help.

Comment: The density function is the derivative of the distribution function. Where can this derivative be computed, where can it not?

Comment: Everything looks ok, except point  $0$.

Comment: Indeed, at $x=0$ the distribution function $F$ has what could be described as infinite slope, since it jumps from $0$ to $\tfrac 1 2$. For the density function $f$ this would mean an infinitely large value $f(0)$, so that if you integrate over it, the area just below that value would be $\tfrac 1 2$. This is impossible for a function $f\colon \mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ of course.

Comment: Thank you very much for help, it helped me a lot.